# Joomla like image selector for custom cms

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system

i am creating insert article page for my custom cms, i would like to have a inset image option like the one in joomla, where i can select picture from specific folder with small thumbs.

does anybody knows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla uses TinyMCE editor out of the box. You should be able to use that. It's open source and independent.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/